# Embed SVG with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I am developing a SVG viewer for a web application. I have to work with existing SVG files and deal with them to show tooltips, do effects with mouse events...

I have looked for a good library to do that and RaphaelJS seems useful and it has IE compatibility (even IE8).

However, after several attemps, I can't get the embed element with SVG throught Raphael.

Is this not possible? If not, How can I do it?

My code where I load SVG files is:

```
<embed wmode="transparent" id="viewer" src="svg/mouseover.svg" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as fas as i know, raphael is not used to embed existing svg in web pages. instead, its purpose is to allow you to use javascript to create svg dynamically

see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

EDIT:
have a look at https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import, though

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you know if I could do with jQuery SVG? I must be able to manage mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have reached the solution using jQuery SVG (http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) instead of RaphaelJS (http://raphaeljs.com/).

This is the code using this plugin:

```
var svgDoc = $(document.getElementById("viewer").getSVGDocument().documentElement);
$(svgDoc.get(0)).svg();
var svg = $(svgDoc).svg('get');
```

Moreover, this code works for the majority of browsers (IE8, IE9, Firefox y Chrome).